# I want to open navigation page from App.js file (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation, react-native-track-player

I need to open audio single page on click notification bar

```
  componentDidMount() {
    Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => this.handleUrl({ url: url }));
    Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleUrl);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleUrl);
  }

  handleUrl = async (data) => {
    if (data.url === 'trackplayer://notification.click') {
      const slug = await TrackPlayer.getCurrentTrack()
      console.log(slug);
      RootNavigation.navigate({
        routeName: 'Player',
        params: {
          slug: slug,
        },
        key: 'player' + slug
      })  
    }
  };
```

https://github.com/DoubleSymmetry/react-native-track-player/issues/346#issuecomment-450512039
I tried this working
but now i want to open page from `App.js` file (navigation showing undefined)

i tried also this for https://stackoverflow.com/a/65299433/12716902

Comment: Can you show how you created your `RootNavigation`?

Comment: @Auticcat i used same as defined in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65299433/9606095

Comment: Try looking at [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/)